# Create new report from template is not working (CiviCRM 4.6.5)

Tags: civireport

When you go to /civicrm/report/template/list?reset=1
and for example choose this contact report template
/civicrm/report/contact/summary?reset=1
..and click on the button 'Create report'
Then a popup window appears with 
Report Title
Report Description
..and when you click the button 'Continue', the popup window disappears and nothing happens. No report is created.

I tried different browsers, but the problem stays the same.

[image]

Comment: By the way, previous version (4.6.3) had the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared that this was caused by a theme that I applied to civicrm.
I reverted to the original bartik theme and the report creation worked.